# Multilingual Symfony2 website

Tags: php, symfony, multilingual

I have a huge problem that I couldn't resolve in the last few days. I don't expect you to give me a final solution because I think the problem is not so simple.
So I have a huge Symfony2 application that was built with the idea to work only with one language. All routes are in their responsible controllers. Now I want to prefix all routes with the selected language so could have:

```
myapp.com/en/news
myapp.com/fr/news
etc...
```

And if it is possible the default language should not be shown in the route - if English is my default language I want only *myapp.com/news*. The problem is that I can't just go through all routes and make them work both with optional parameter about the language and also work without that parameter. If it is not possible I am ok *en* to be presented in the route too.

I tried the [jmsi18nroutingbundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) because  many other people suggested it but when I setup the config.yml as it is said only some of the routes get prefix when I check them with **app/console debug:router**. And because of that I am either not configuring it well or it has some limitations.

My question is how do you handle multilingual websites and their routes - do you start with the idea about multilingual system from the beginning and create at least two routes for each action one with optional parameter about the language and one without that parameter or you have more global solution to handle all routes?

Comment: Have you read through: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html  _locale is fairly magical

Comment: Yes but it says that the language can be omitted if default is set but it is not. When I try to access the route without language I get page not found error

Comment: Then I would suggest you ask for help solving that, setting a default language should allow you to visit the site without _locale set in the url

Comment: I would ask that but there might be better solutions and that's why I ask about bigger picture solutions

Comment: You always need a locale in the route.  You can set a default locale with https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#setting-a-default-locale which means you can generate routes without explicitly setting a locale.  If you want your app to behave differently then I think you are pretty much on your own.

Comment: if I have an optional parameter at the beginng as is **_locale** doesn't it become required because if it is optional and I have /en/new, **_locale** for /news will be set as _news_ and will expect one more parameter after that called _news_ so it can reach my news page with **_locale** set to news